# Google has deindexed portions of our page after content copied

Tags: seo, search-results, copyright, ctr

This year our website featured in a number of top design articles and has been subsequently copied extensively. Now, Google appears to have deindexed portions of our home page (and maybe other content) which is causing concern for our SEO rankings and CTR.

Furthermore, it no longer reads key portions of the page to present in SERP, instead converting our navigation to text. The results, as you can imagine, are very poor (refer image).

[image]

We're a Christian organisation and are not interested in pursuing copyright infringements.

What can be done about this?

Comment: Your SERP might be affected by your personal "filter bubble". The highlighted text suggests that your query was "church" as that is being highlighted here. Google won't always use your meta description and will often generate a description from the page content. In this case your query was matched in high density somewhere in your navigation and it chose to use this instead

Comment: I did a little digging on google.com and google.co.nz, including a site:yourwebsite.com search and the SERP was showing what is listed in your description. Seems fine on my end and probably nothing to worry about. Maybe try some test searches in incognito mode and see if you are still getting that "bubbled" result